# How to enable scrollEdgeAppearance manually?

Tags: uinavigationbar, uinavigationbarappearance

I have a controller **without large title**, I noticed that appearance in detail pane of `UISplitViewController` will enable `scrollEdgeAppearance` automantically.

[image: Settings App]

So how can I use `scrollEdgeAppearance` in other controller?